# Late 80s or early 90s anime\cartoon in space with slugs and pink tentacles

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation

I'll do my best to remember everything I can -

The very first scene is a father that is combining a crop, he is using a futuristic machine as this movie involves space, aliens, etc.

The planet ends up being destroyed very early in the movie, the father dies but the son who is about 17-20 is taken away on a spaceship. I believe he is knocked unconscious.

This is where it gets harder to remember. There ends up being a planet they land on where there are pink fuzzy like tentacles I believe that end up capturing them. But they are saved by a flying alien that has guns attached to his hips. Best way to kinda explain him, piccolo with a mask and wings.

Later the protagonists end up dealing with slugs that are trying to eat them.

The main protagonist ends up being badly injured, an old guy I believe takes care of him.

Then the end is him going to a weird dance like party to save his friends.

This is about the best amount of detail I can give, it's a very strange movie but was recorded on vhs and never was written down what is was called. So I have no idea.

Hope you all can help.

Comment: This sounds oddly like "Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back"

Comment: Titan A.E.? Maybe a duplicate of http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/40906/looking-for-an-80s-or-90s-animated-childrens-film-featuring-a-flying-ship-bo/

Comment: Sadly not Titan ae, as well the one character is more like an early cell than piccolo. I believe it's more of an anime than cartoon.

Answer (score 4):

[Lensman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088028/), (1984), loosely based on Edward E "Doc" Smith's "Lensman" books.

> Kimball Kinnison, a young man from the **agricultural planet** Mquie and
>   his Valerian companinon, Buscirk find a dying man with a legendary
>   crystal lens embedded in his hand. As the man was dying, he
>   mysteriously passed on the Lens to Kim. With more companions to come
>   by, Kim must find out the purpose of the Lens before the Boskone
>   dynasty does.

The movie is available [on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_g5xFo8YowQ).  The scene with the pink fuzzy tentacles is [here](https://youtu.be/_g5xFo8YowQ?t=2401).  The flying alien with guns attached to his hips is "Worsel".  The weird dance party is DJ'ed by "DJ Bill".